# How to add custom gradient summaries to tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm training a tf.keras model and would like to use the TensorBoard callback to write the gradients to disk during the training. Specifically, for every trainable variable I'm computing the mean Euclidean norm of its gradient at a given step and writing it to a scalar summary buffer like so:

```
def add_mean_norm_summary(variable, scope):
    with tf.name_scope(scope):
        mean_l2_norm = tf.norm(variable, ord='euclidean') / tf.to_float(tf.size(variable))
        return tf.summary.scalar('{}_mean_l2_norm'.format(scope), mean_l2_norm)
```

I wrote a custom tf.keras.optimizer.Optimizer that inherits from an existing optimizer (in my case Adam), and overrode its `get_updates()` method like so:

```
def get_updates(self, loss, params):

    grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)

    grad_summaries = []
    for grad, param in zip(grads, params):
        summary_name_scope = param.name.replace(':', '_') + '_gradient'
        grad_summaries.append(add_mean_norm_summary(grad, summary_name_scope))
    tf.summary.merge(grad_summaries, name='gradient_summaries')
```

I was hoping that I could then write a custom TensorBoard callback that inherits from `tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard` where I could somehow grab these summaries and add them to the file writer in the `on_batch_end()` method. So far I've been unsuccessful. I've tried to call the merged summaries op by name from my derived TensorBoard class, but it's telling me that there is no such op in the graph.

Does anybody know how to do this properly?